# Kendo UI FileUpload via AJAX with JSON

Tags: ajax, json, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo with MVC 5.   I have several form inputs including a fileupload control.   Onclick of a button I am building a json object with the values of the inputs and sending it through via an AJAX call.

I want to know how I can include the selected file from the file upload control in the json object that is sent.  Here is the code for the upload control:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
        multiple: false
    });
});
```

And then the ajax call sending the form data:

```
var ro = new Object();
// ...... //populate some properties      
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(ro);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Service")',
    data: jsonString ,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
});
```

The receiving controller action look like this:

```
public ActionResult Save(MyViewModel model)
{
    var obj = //call something here then return resulting obj 
    return this.Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @cmedine- were you able to do this? could you please post the solutiion

Comment: I was not able to get it working and implemented a temporary storage solution that gets cleared upon app restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#files").kendoUpload({
            multiple: false,
            async: {
                saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "Service")',
                autoUpload: true
            },
            upload: function (e) {
                var ro = new Object();
                //......//populate some properties      

                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(ro);
                e.data = jsonString;
            }
        });
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string model) 
            // string because you used JSON.stringify and it is a string, do not stringify, if you need an object
        {
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objetModel = js.Deserialize<MyViewModel>(model);            

            var obj = //call something here then return resulting obj 

            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

I did not test it - it is just to get you an idea how to pass an additional information along with the uploaded binary file

Comment: Thanks however the upload control is not using async - I don't want to upload anything until they choose to Submit